# is there any way to get multiple tags changed with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have to change multiple `<p>` styles with JavaScript from an external file, and I could not find a way.
I have tried with `document.getElementsByTagName("p").style.color = "red"` and it did not work.

Someone can help me?

Comment: getElementsByTagname returns a NodeList. You need to iterate over the list and change each element's style individually. Also, look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

Comment: Can you not create your own css file to override these instead of using js?

Comment: @Huangism It has to be done with JS its like that the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file with filename

> scriptname.js

with these contents:

```
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    ps[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

and in your html file, import the javascript with:

```
<script src="scriptname.js">
</script>
```

So your two files would be:

```js
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
    // console.log(i);
    ps[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Javascript imported
    </title>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>a</p>
   <p>b</p>
   <p>c</p>
   <p>d</p>
   <p>e</p>
   <p>f</p>
   <p>g</p>


   <script src="hey.js">
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked perfectly but  i could not make it work from the external file.

Comment: I updated the answer. Make sure they are in the same directory. Read about [file paths on HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).

Comment: I have the html linked correctly i guess because it launches an alert or prompt. But not the code that you sent me ort other one that i did.

Comment: `code`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Evaluación 4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/codigos.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: alert('hola')

`code`.  var ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
  ps[i].style.color = "red";
}

Comment: @Marina.eq put your javascript import inside and  below all the contents of your HTML `body`. I updated the code on HTML. You need to import the javascript after the elements you want already EXISTS.